# Remove ECC warnings in system log

Tags: linux-kernel, kali-linux, dmesg, ecc

How can I disable these warnings about ECC? I don't have ECC memory and so disabled it in bios also but it still prints it.

```
[    4.697057] EDAC amd64: Node 0: DRAM ECC disabled.
[    4.697061] EDAC amd64: ECC disabled in the BIOS or no ECC capability, module will not load.
                Either enable ECC checking or force module loading by setting 'ecc_enable_override'.
                (Note that use of the override may cause unknown side effects.)
[    4.764909] EDAC amd64: Node 0: DRAM ECC disabled.
[    4.764911] EDAC amd64: ECC disabled in the BIOS or no ECC capability, module will not load.
                Either enable ECC checking or force module loading by setting 'ecc_enable_override'.
                (Note that use of the override may cause unknown side effects.)
[    4.844621] EDAC amd64: Node 0: DRAM ECC disabled.
[    4.844624] EDAC amd64: ECC disabled in the BIOS or no ECC capability, module will not load.
                Either enable ECC checking or force module loading by setting 'ecc_enable_override'.
                (Note that use of the override may cause unknown side effects.)
[    4.889875] EXT4-fs (sda2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[    4.892678] EDAC amd64: Node 0: DRAM ECC disabled.
[    4.892681] EDAC amd64: ECC disabled in the BIOS or no ECC capability, module will not load.
                Either enable ECC checking or force module loading by setting 'ecc_enable_override'.
                (Note that use of the override may cause unknown side effects.)
[    4.913651] EXT4-fs (sdc1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[    4.936635] EDAC amd64: Node 0: DRAM ECC disabled.
[    4.936637] EDAC amd64: ECC disabled in the BIOS or no ECC capability, module will not load.
                Either enable ECC checking or force module loading by setting 'ecc_enable_override'.
                (Note that use of the override may cause unknown side effects.)
[    4.949722] EXT4-fs (sda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[    4.980600] EDAC amd64: Node 0: DRAM ECC disabled.
[    4.980602] EDAC amd64: ECC disabled in the BIOS or no ECC capability, module will not load.
                Either enable ECC checking or force module loading by setting 'ecc_enable_override'.
                (Note that use of the override may cause unknown side effects.)
[    5.028880] EDAC amd64: Node 0: DRAM ECC disabled.
[    5.028883] EDAC amd64: ECC disabled in the BIOS or no ECC capability, module will not load.
                Either enable ECC checking or force module loading by setting 'ecc_enable_override'.
                (Note that use of the override may cause unknown side effects.)
```

Comment: Have you tried blacklisting the module?
`echo 'blacklist ecc' >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`

Comment: No I didn't I just happened to notice it in a log file.

Comment: I will try to and see the result

Comment: it doesn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't have an ECC-capable memory, you can try to find and subsequently disable this spammy module:

```
find /lib/modules/$(uname -r) -type f -name '*.ko' | grep _edac
```

There will be quite a lot of `*_edac*` modules, but in your case the culprit module is `amd64_edac_mod` (as hinted in the error message).

Then all you have to do is to put this module into the blacklist file:

```
echo "blacklist amd64_edac_mod" >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Reboot, voilà! — the module is not attempted to be loaded anymore and the error is gone.

Comment: Thank you for the hint.

Comment: You're very welcome!